# Permission denied on apache when I load php with ZMQ

Tags: php, apache, centos, zeromq

I have this php script that connects to a zmq server.
I am using the example code from the manual ([http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter1](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3achapter1))

On the command line everything works fine.
When I load the php script via apache I get this on apaches error log

```
Permission denied (signaler.cpp:120)
[Mon Jun 02 09:41:36 2014] [notice] child pid 12055 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

So the page doesn't even load. I suppose signaler.cpp is from libzmq but I don't really know what to do with this.
Anyone know how to fix this?

```
System info:

PHP 5.3.3

ZMQ extension => enabled

ZMQ extension version => 1.1.2

libzmq version => 3.2.2

OS: Centos 6
```

**Edit**

Found the problem. It was SELinux!

Comment: Have you checked the permission for the file signaler.cpp. Does it have necessary file permissions so that apache can execute?

Comment: check you have chmod + for the file and also ownership rights